# Python pandas - change last hour of a day 00 with 24

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, hour

I'm currently working on setting up a pandas dataframe. I have a date time column, which should be splitted onto date and time columns. 
I have reached to split this column to date + time columns like this:

```
        Date       Hour
22      20200205   23  
23      20200205   00
```

What I want is to replace 00 value with 24. I know Python does not recognize 24th hour as the last our, but for my purposes, I need to include "24" hour.

I'm pretty new to python and pandas and I'm confused about replacing this value.
I tried to use below code line but with no luck: 
frame= OMPdata

```
OMPdata['Hour'] = OMPdata['Hour'].str.replace(00,24, case= False)
```

or function:

```
def h24 (row):
                if row['Hour'] == "00":
                    return "24"
                else: 
                    return row['Hour']
```

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `df.Hour = df.Hour.astype(str).replace('00', '24')`

Comment: `00` is a string not a number

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to do the right thing? The convention is that Monday 24:00 == Tuesday 00:00. That is basically the only time hour 24 will occur in timestamps (the other being leap seconds). If you're only giving hours, I would still expect a day to go from hour 0 (the hour where times start with 00:...) to hour 23, and not from hour 1 to hour 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to first convert to string the column and then replace:

```
df['Hour'] = df['Hour'].astype(str)
df['Hour'] = df['Hour'].str.replace("00","24", case= False)
```